# ajax: login form not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

I am trying to process my login form using ajax, I have a html form and some ajax script which posts the data to my login.php page and checks for user authentication. Then if the user is authenticated they will be redirected to the dashboard, otherwise if the user does not pass authentication I want an alert message to show up.

For some reason this is not working. please can someone show me where I am going wrong. thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
 <div class="home_column">
<div class="login_form">
<form name="login" id="login"> 
<h21>Username</h21><br/>
<input type="text" class="login_form_front" id="myusername" name="myusername"><br/>
<h21>Password</h21><br/>
<input type="password" class="login_form_front" autocomplete="off"  id="mypassword" name="mypassword">
<br/>
<input type="submit" class="buttons_login" value="Login" id="submit" name="submit">
</form> 
</div>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#submit").click(function(){

                    var sel_stud2 = $('#myusername').val();
                    var sel_stud1 = $('#mypassword').val();
//alert('You picked: ' + sel_stud);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "include/check_log.php",
                        data: {theOption2: sel_stud2, theOption3: sel_stud1}, 
                        success: function(whatigot) {
//alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
      alert("Login failed.");                        
                   } //END success fn
                    }); //END $.ajax
                }); //END dropdown change event
            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
```

my login.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");

$tbl_name="internal_users";  

//Get value posted in by ajax
$myusername = $_POST['theOption2'];
$mypassword = $_POST['theOption3'];


$sql = "select * from $tbl_name where user_name = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row) {
header("location:../dashboard.php")
}else{

} ?>
```

Comment: Does AJAX request arrive to backend? What dous dashboard.php do? Does DB have a user with the tried username & password -combo? I suggest you learn something about SQL-injection and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget that the cal of header() dont change the URL of your site. Only the AJAX call will be forwarded!

Otherwise code seems to be OK. But as heikkim said, have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Check if your SQL statement runs. Do some output in the else statement and catch it in the success method of jquery instead of this Login failed message:

```
alert(whatigot);
```

Comment: I think you will get your dashboard in "whatigot"!